# Customise <control>+ click action on Strings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a plugin and I want that when I  click on some String Literal, it opens a text file editor having the same string.
Sequence of Action:
1. Click on the String
2. Search a Folder for all the text files
3. Search the existence of the clicked string.
4. If the String exists open the text editor in eclipse.

I am new to plugin development , I found that we may use Extension-points for this namely hyperlinkDetector, but I am not able to understand how can I use it. I modified the plugin.xml and also craeted two classes implementing IHyperlinkDetector and IHyperlinkAny but when I debug the plugin  and perform control click my code is not reached.

Comment: Show us your full code. I try search for you working example and I have found it in the first link
http://codeandme.blogspot.ru/2014/06/adding-hyperlink-detectors-to-editors.html

Comment: @EvgeniyK. Yes this is exactly what I did, and implemented the same very code, but it does not work. The control never reaches to the class which implements IHyperlinkDetector. This working example itself isnt working for me

Comment: And do you implement this "PreferencesHyperlink implements IHyperlink"?

Comment: @Prateek try posting a comment on the blog and see if Christian (codeandme author) can update the download link which is currently 404.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. Yes I did implement both of them. May be there is a problem in the location where I kept the two files.

Comment: @JonahGraham @Prateek The download link is a 404 due to Google Code shutting down. The file is still available if you download the entire repository's [archive](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/codeandme/source-archive.zip) and extract it (the file in question is then at the path `codeandme/trunk/blog/Code & Me Blog/hyperlink_detector.zip`).

Comment: @HighCommander4 Thanks :)